# Is it normal to have Informix users with PID=0?

Tags: jdbc, informix

I have several service applications that use Informix JDBC driver. When they connects to the database I can see their sessions via `onstat` utility, but most of them have PID=0. Is it normal to have such PID?

```
bash-4.2$ onstat -g ses |grep ' 0 '
461436   informix -        0        -        0        16384      12352      off
461434   h_s2kole -        0        mcintv1  1        438272     411696     off
461387   h_zgodyp -        0        mcintv1  1        421888     346112     off
461373   h_zgodyp -        0        mcintv1  1        548864     381240     off
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's normal.

Informix JDBC Driver will always report `0` or `-1`.

I had the notion that it’s platform depended, windows should be `0` and `-1` for the others.

But I believe it has to do with the compilation itself, not the running.